# How do I close a loading screen right when the other thread is finished in Python using Tk?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, consumer, producer

I have a Python GUI that uses Tkinter. I have to SSH into another place to get data. I start a new thread to do this so that the GUI doesn't hang. During this time, I want to pop up a screen that lets the user know it is loading. Once the program is finished getting the data, I want to close the loading screen. What must I do to have my main loop recognize that the thread is done? I've tried to use that thread to close the loading screen that exists in the main loop, but then I discovered that doesn't work.

I have seen some producer consumer models that don't use GUIs, and they have while loops. This doesn't help me though. I also don't want to download and install other packages, but imports are ok. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your thread set a flag when it is done. Have the GUI periodically check for that flag and dismiss the window when it is set.

You can check for the flag by creating a function that checks for the flag, and if it's not set it uses `after` to have itself run again a few hundred ms later. The window won't go away immediately after the thread exits, but as long as the lag isn't more than a couple hundred ms the user will never notice.

Comment: Could Jack alternatively have the secondary thread raise a virtual event that would be bound to the GUI?

Comment: Maybe. Tkinter isn't thread safe but perhaps the raise method won't cause problems. It' worth a try I suppose.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! I used your suggestion of using the "after" to continuously poll. Is it ok long term to have this keep polling? Does this waste system resources?

Comment: @Jack: the use of resources is minimal, almost to the point of being unmeasurable (assuming all it does is check a flag), though there's no point in keeping it running once it's done its job and dismissed the loading screen.